# Newbie question in Raphael animation

Tags: raphael, graphael

I am a newbie in Raphael. Here I got a problem.

I have defined a path:

`var c = paper.path('M '+p1.x+' '+p1.y+'L '+p2.x+' '+p2.y);`

where `p1`,`p2` are two end points of the path.

I would like to have a animation feature that when mouse click on the path, p2 will collapse to p1 and finally p2 will be "hide by p1" as they overlapse. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't animate a path properties. Best to redraw the path with different properties. So you would "animate" the variables for p1 and redraw the path with those variables.

You need a timer function which alters the p1 parameters. So that every 0.1 second in example the p1 parameters go near the p2 ones.

```
var p1x = 10;
var p1y = 10;

var p2x = 20;
var p2y = 20;

var t = setTimeout("timer()", 100);
var p = paper.path(...);

function timer()
{
   p1x++;
   p1y++;

   p.remove();
   p = paper.path(with new variables);

   if(p1x == p2x) clearTimeout(t);
}
```

Somebody else struggling with it: http://japhr.blogspot.com/2010/09/cant-animate-raphael-path-positions.html